# jQuery(div#id) behaviour to invalid html

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

What will `jQuery("div#someid")` return if the html is invalid and has many div elements with the same "someid". Will it return the first of those divs ? Or is that random ?

Comment: Why dont you try it yourself ? :O

Comment: [Just read the docs](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) - "If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM."

Comment: Id's should be unique. Give them a common class instead.

Comment: @Jashwant, there is a difference between teaching how to fish, giving fish and whatever it is you are doing :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The selector will give different results in different browsers.

Some testing shows these results:

```
Firefox 19: All elements
IE 10: All elements
IE 9: All elements
IE 8: All elements
IE 7: One element
Chrome 25: All elements
```

The result might also vary with other factors, like jQuery version, page rendering mode and operating system. You simply can't expect a consistent result with conflicting id attributes.

Comment: This actually only has to do with the fact that `div#someid` as a CSS selector is *supposed* to return all elements with the same ID regardless of whether your markup is conforming. IE7 is the only browser among those listed that doesn't support the native Selectors API and as such does not use it to process valid CSS selectors passed to jQuery, and from the results it's evident that jQuery treats selectors differently from the spec. That said, the last sentence still holds true; just don't use duplicate IDs to save yourself unnecessary headaches.

Comment: Note also that the behaviour of `"div#someid"` is different to when you omit the `div` part and just use `"#test"` - the latter will return only one element.

Answer (score 2):

The best to know that is try it out, see it in action in this fiddle http://tinker.io/cba17 , so the answer is it will return a set with all the divs that have that id. Although please avoid that situation because it is invalid html and use a class instead.

Also notice there's a difference between using `$('#someid'`) and `$('div#someid')`  :

`$('#someid'`) will return the first div with that id.

`$('div#someid')` will return the complete set with all elements as showed in the fiddle I posted above.

Comment: This difference lies in the fact that jQuery special-cases lone ID selectors. Attaching anything else to the ID will result in the behavior I describe in my comment on Guffa's answer.

Comment: Thank you for the demo, now i know how to test and find answer to my future queries on js..

Answer (score 0):

having same id is invalid... so you should avoid that... and use class...(though no error is thrown) 
anyways  the selector will return first occurance of that div having same id..